# Jquery Replacing space in string with html <br /> tag

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I want to replace spaces in a string with a html `<br />` tag, whats the best way of doing this?. Currently I have this code which replaces the spaces with a "-".

```
$(".msn").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/ /g, '-'));
});
```

Comment: well... `.replace(/ /g, '<br/>')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".msn").html(function(i, oldHTML) {
    return oldHTML.replace(/ /g, '<br/>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.html()` instead of `.text()`:

```
$(".msn").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/ /g, '<br />'));
});
```

Comment: I haven't checked, but what about white-space inside element tags and attributes? This doesn't *seem* entirely safe.

Comment: @DavidThomas - I'd think changing the second .html() to .text() would resolve that.